# How to add digit before first character of string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string, and I need to get its first character. if that character is alphabetic (between A to Z or a to z)then i want add any digit in-front of that character

```
var x = 'somestring'
alert(x.charAt(0));
```

in above string first character has alphabet then i need to attach any digit (0 to 9) before string

```
4somestring
```

How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (/[a-zA-Z]/.test(x.charAt(0))) {
    x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)) + x;
}
```

Simply use regexes, the `test` method, and `Math.random`.

You could also use an anchor so you don't have to call `charAt`:

```
if (/^[a-zA-Z]/.test(x)) {
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yvYvy/).

Answer (score -2):

```
var x = 'somestring';
if (! /^\d+$/.test(x[0]))
    x = 5 + x; // or some other number
```

Comment: That's for arrays, not strings.

Comment: ...no, it's not. They are two completely different types. `'someString'.unshift => undefined`